# Interface a CML device with FPGA

Tags: fpga, interface, standard, lvds

I want to interface an IC with an FPGA however I noticed that the datasheet says the digital control inputs are differential and CML standard based. Can someone please guide how to interface this if I use LVDS as output standard on FPGA for connecting with this device and do interface conversion in between?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to to do.  Do you want to use  LVDS inputs on your FPGA to accept signals from your CML device?  If so, there are a number of app notes at there that address this.

Comment: One good reference is the TI app note snla187, "LVDS Owner's Manual".  Another reference from TI is SLLD009 "LVDS Application and Data Handbook".  Both of these are from the early 2000's.

Comment: Or SLLA101 "Interfacing Different Logic with LVDS Receivers" or SLLA120 "Interfacing Between LVPECL, VML, CML and LVDS Levels".

Comment: @SteveSh Sorry for lack of clarity in the question, I meant on using LVDS as output standard on FPGA and do standard conversion to CML, is that ok and how can it be done?

Comment: @CL. Thank you for sharing the document but it is for LVDS receivers but in this case the LVDS is to be used as a driver or if there is any easier alternative than LVDS on FPGA please share as well

Comment: Oops, I meant of course SCAA059 "AC-Coupling Between Differential LVPECL, LVDS, HSTL, and CML" and SCAA062 "DC-Coupling Between Differential LVPECL, LVDS, HSTL, and CML". And there is the SN65CML100.

Comment: @CL. Thank you that is just what I was looking for, kindly post this in answer and I'll mark it as correct. Just to confirm, I can assume these methods will hold for other vendors as well in case I don't find other vendor specific documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document mentioned by CL. SCAA059 "AC-Coupling Between Differential LVPECL, LVDS, HSTL, and CML" and SCAA062 "DC-Coupling Between Differential LVPECL, LVDS, HSTL, and CML" gives detail of the conversion.